# Pandas Timezone Aware Index Drops Timezone When Converting To Series

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the time index of a dataframe as a series, but it appears to be dropping the timezone when I call the method to_series. Below is an example. Is this a bug or am I doing something incorrectly?

```
rows = 50
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(rows,2), columns=list('AB'), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=rows, freq='1H', tz=pytz.UTC))

print df.index[-1]
# 2000-01-03 01:00:00+00:00

print df.index.to_series()[-1]
# 2000-01-03 01:00:00


print df.index[-1].tzinfo
# UTC

print df.index.to_series()[-1].tzinfo
#None
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you are not doing something wrong, and neither it is a bug.
It is a **currently known limitation** of pandas/numpy: timezones aware datetime data are only supported in the index. In a series, the data are stored as numpy `datetime64` types, which does not support timezones. There is an open issue for adding this timezone feature also to series: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8260

A workaround is to store your data as `object` dtype instead of `datetime64` (then they will be stored as `Timestamp` objects, a subclass of `datetime.datetime`). This will enable you to keep the timezone info.
`to_series` has a `keep_tz` keyword argument to obtain this (see [docstring](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_series.html)):

```
In [34]: df = df.tz_convert('US/Eastern')

In [35]: df.index.to_series()[-1]
Out[35]: Timestamp('2000-01-03 01:00:00')

In [36]: df.index.to_series(keep_tz=True)[-1]
Out[36]: Timestamp('2000-01-02 20:00:00-0500', tz='US/Eastern', offset='H')
```